# Nested directory searching

Tags: ruby, directory, nested

I'm trying to make a program that searches through hopefully every directory, sub directory, sub sub directory and so on in `C:\`. I feel like I can take care of that part, but there's also the issue of the folder names. There may be case issues like a folder named `FOO` not being dected when my program searches for `Foo` or a giant `if`/`else` or `case` statement for multiple search criteria.

My questions are: 1. is there a way to ignore letter case? and 2. is there a way to make a more efficient statement for searching?

My current code:

```
#foldersniffer by Touka, ©2015
base = Dir.entries("C:\\")
trees = Dir.entries("#{base}")
trees.each do |tree|
    if Dir.exist?("Foo")
        puts "Found Folder \"Foo\" in C:\\"
    elsif Dir.exist?("Bar")
        puts "Found Folder \"Bar\" in C:\\"
    else
        puts "No folders found"
    end
end
sleep
```

any help is appreciated.

**edit**: it's trying to scan files like bootmgr and it's giving me errors... I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: Now what's your question?

Comment: From where you found the `scan` method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [`Dir.glob(...)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) and regular expressions for case insensitive matching:

```ruby
Dir.glob('c:\\**\*') do |filename|
  if filename =~ /c:\\(foo|bar)($|\\)/i
    puts "Found #{filename}"
  end
end
```

Case sensitivity for the `Dir.glob` argument is likely not relevant on Windows systems:

> Note that this pattern is not a regexp, it’s closer to a shell glob. See File.fnmatch for the meaning of the flags parameter. Note that case sensitivity depends on your system (so File::FNM_CASEFOLD is ignored), as does the order in which the results are returned.

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert enough to say for sure but I would look into File::FNM_CASEFOLD

https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/04/14/case-insensitive-dir-glob-in-ruby-really-it-has-to-be-that-cryptic/